# Why does Capistrano ask for the ssh key's passphrase twice?

Tags: ssh, capistrano

Whenever I deploy using capistrano I am prompted to enter the passphrase twice. Why is that and how can I resolve it?

```
    servers: ["example.com"]
    [example.com] executing command
 ** [example.com :: out] Enter passphrase for key '/home/deploy/.ssh/deploy-keys/appname':
Password: 
 ** [example.com :: out]
 ** [example.com :: out] Enter passphrase for key '/home/deploy/.ssh/deploy-keys/appname':
Password: 
 ** [example.com :: out]
    command finished in 16748ms
```

Comment: Having the same problem here. Were you able to resolve it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Capistrano cannot handle itself multiple servers with passphrased keys.
You have to use that before :

```
ssh-add /path/to/your/key.pem
```

This loads the key in your console sessions.
Then you can deploy on multiple servers without writing the passphrase.